# How this loop will ever end

Tags: c++, while-loop

Opening Again
Edit :
How to end this one

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> s;
    string word;

    while(cin >> word)
        {
            s.push_back(word);
        }



        for(auto i =0; i < s.size(); i++)
        {
            for(auto &c : s[i])
            c = toupper(c);
        }

        int j=1;
        for(auto c : s)
        {
              cout << c << " ";
              if(j%8==0)
              {
                  cout << "\n";
              }
              j++;
        }  
}
```

1. Other method can be used like putting word != "end" or something like that in while loop but it will create and extra word which i dont want.
2. I am not getting a thing why when i give space between two words like, Hello my name is james(in input) then why c++ treats it like different string and strors in different blocks of vector. I am new at c++ programming as you can see, but a old C programmer, not very old 3 month older, college guy.

---

This is an example from book c++ primer 5th edition.
My question how this while loop will end I tried everything like enter, entering 0
there a many examples in this book like this.

```
int main()
{
      vector<unsigned> scores(11, 0);          
      unsigned grade;
      while (cin >> grade)
      { 
            if (grade <= 100) // handle only valid grades
            ++scores[grade/10];
      }

      for(auto c : scores)
      {
           cout << c << endl;
      }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl-D?

Comment: ...or (if you're running it on Windows) <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: ... or (also if you're running it on Windows) Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Nothing worked Crtl+D and F6

Comment: Okay thanks every one, hitting enter after Crtl + Z works
System : Windows using Codeblock IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `cin >> grade` yields false (when evaluated as boolean) if the input operation failed. This happens if you reach the end of the input (EOF) or if the itput could not be parsed as the according type. Since whitespace is skipped, hitting enter doesn't exit the loop. Since a zero is a valid unsigned number, that doesn't trigger loop exit either. Entering a letter would do the job, or the (OS-specific) key combo to signal EOF.

Comment: For completeness - another useful option is redirection ala `echo 80 70 60 20 | ./my_app` or `./my_app < test_data.txt`.  Cheers.

Comment: In first example Op's showing cin >> std::string. So trick with "Entering a letter" won't do the job.

Comment: Well, the question was edited to something different. Little surprise that the answer doesn't apply any more.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `(cin >> end)` has a return value: the object `cin`. This is what allows you to do stuff like `cin >> x >> y`. 
The reason the loop ends is that the boolean (truth) value of the object `cin` is equal to the status of the input (probably your terminal) that it is reading from. If it reaches the end of input, `cin` will be evaluated as `false` and the loop ends.

As the commenters have said, you can use Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z in a terminal to cause `cin` to read the "End of File" marker.